# How should I represent a value of None when a [Flags] enum type doesn't define it?

Tags: c#, enum-flags

While working with XNA today, I noticed that one of the enum types that uses `[Flags]` did not have a `None = 0` value:

```
[Flags]
public enum Buttons
{
    DPadUp = 1,
    DPadDown = 2,
    DPadLeft = 4,
    DPadRight = 8,
    Start = 16,
    Back = 32,
    LeftStick = 64,
    RightStick = 128,
    LeftShoulder = 256,
    RightShoulder = 512,
    BigButton = 2048,
    A = 4096,
    B = 8192,
    X = 16384,
    Y = 32768,
    LeftThumbstickLeft = 2097152,
    RightTrigger = 4194304,
    LeftTrigger = 8388608,
    RightThumbstickUp = 16777216,
    RightThumbstickDown = 33554432,
    RightThumbstickRight = 67108864,
    RightThumbstickLeft = 134217728,
    LeftThumbstickUp = 268435456,
    LeftThumbstickDown = 536870912,
    LeftThumbstickRight = 1073741824,
}
```

According to MSDN regarding the [proper use of the `[Flags]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx):

> Do name the zero value of flags enumerations `None`. For a flags enumeration, the value must always mean all flags are cleared.

If I wanted to indicate a value where no buttons are pressed, would it go against the intent of the enum type to use a value of 0 and cast it to `Buttons`? According to the design guidelines, it *should* have this value, but it doesn't.

Comment: The enum is used in the GamePadState.IsButtonUp/Down() methods.  It makes no sense to ask if no button is down with those methods.  So it didn't make sense to include None.  You can't change the type, it is baked into XNA, but since 0 is always a valid value for an enum you can always use default(Buttons).

Comment: I figured it was something like that. I'm not fond of how button polling is handled differently for each input type (mouse buttons don't even have their own enum type, unlike the keyboard and gamepad). My current project is making a common wrapper class around the different types of input that eg holds a current and previous `KeyboardState`, so that I can easily poll whether a key or button was just pressed or released. As a result, I can either have clients poll the IsPressed() methods I make or subscribe to events, so this was a consequence of making GamePadEventArgs contain a Buttons value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Since it is a `Flags` enum, the state of none of the possible values being set is going to be `(Buttons)0` (or `default(Buttons)` if you'd prefer to indicate it in some way that reflects the type directly in your code), whether the designer of the type assigned a name to it or not.

Consider that if we can express "no button that isn't the A button is pressed and also the A button isn't pressed" through `Buttons.A & ~Buttons.A` and the result will be `(Buttons)0`. The "no button pressed" state is already `0`.

(The one justification I can think of for leaving out `None` is that you were intending that a type is never used in a case where `None` is the value pressed. E.g., you are only using this for code that reacts to a button being pressed, and hence `None` never comes up. Even then one can find using the `None`/`0` value useful in code, but it can mean that leaving it unnamed is more reasonable).

Comment: You dont even need the cast in `(Buttons)0` :D

Comment: @Leppie: True, but it makes the intent more clear IMO.

Comment: @leppie True. I wasn't even thinking of a cast so much as how to express the fact that the type of `0` is `Buttons` in the context of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without the context. If you would like to represent a state where either something was pressed or not I would go for `Nullable<Buttons>` in this case:

```
class Input
{
    ...
    private Buttons? _buttons;
    ...
}
```

It also shields you from future versions of `Buttons` where `0`*might* be added to mean something other than "None". Yes, unlikely, but not entirely impossible.